# Relative Layout issue in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

I am trying to draw a path on an `ImageView` using the layout below. I couldn't draw a path at the correct position. In the layout, I am using an overlay image one on top of another image.

I think there is a mistake in my layout.xml:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout 
    android:id="@+id/relative"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads">

    <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearlayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal">   

    <ImageButton  android:id="@+id/btngraymode"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/graymode"
    android:layout_marginLeft="4dip"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:padding="3dip"
    android:background="@layout/selector">
    </ImageButton>
    </LinearLayout>


    <com.google.ads.AdView 
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    ads:adUnitId="abcdefgh"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    android:layout_below="@+id/linearlayout1"
    ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"/>

    <view   class="com.labels.android"
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"         
        android:layout_above="@+id/linearlayout"
        android:layout_below="@+id/adView"
        />   

    <view   class="com.labels.android"
        android:id="@+id/image1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_above="@+id/linearlayout"
        android:layout_below="@+id/adView"
        /> 

    <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearlayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/btnselectbackground"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/photo"
    android:layout_marginLeft="4dip"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:padding="3dip"
    android:background="@layout/selector">
    </ImageButton>   
    </LinearLayout>  
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try this with your view tags:

```
 <view   class="com.labels.android"
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"         
    android:layout_above="@+id/image1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/adView"
    />   

<view   class="com.labels.android"
    android:id="@+id/image1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_above="@+id/linearlayout"
    android:layout_below="@+id/adView"
    />
```

You are setting both of your views with ids of image and image1 respectively in the above `LinearLayout`, which is creating the problem. Set first one i.e. image above the image1 and then image1 above linearlayout. Hope this will do it for you.